# Dependence of completion on the base ring

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, ring-spectra

Let $M$ be a module over an $E_\infty$ ring, $A$.  Let $I$ be an $A$-non unital commutative algebra together with an associative map $I \wedge_A M \to M$.

Define ${_A}(M/I^n)$ as the cofiber of $I^{\wedge_A n} \wedge_A M   \to M$, and the completion ${_A}M^\wedge_I$ by $\text{lim}_n {_A}M/I^n$.

I want to understand the dependence of the underlying space of $\text{lim}_n {_A}M/I^n$ on $A$.  Note that the underlying space of ${_A}M/I^n$ depends on $A$.  But sometimes the underlying space of ${_A}M^\wedge_I$ doesn't depend on $A$ since sometimes ${_A}M^\wedge_I=M$.

Comment: What happens if we ask the question just for ordinary rings and modules instead of spectra?

Comment: @user43326 If I interpret discrete in a very naive sense, then its true:  if I interpret cofiber as modding out by the image then $_A M/I^n=M/\text{ image } I^{\otimes_A n} \otimes_A M=M/I^nM$ doesn't depend on $A$.  But if I interpret discrete as meaning eilenberg maclane spectra, I'm not sure :)

Comment: In this case, I'd suspect $_AM/I^n$ depends on $A$ but that the completion does not.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "depends on $A$"? Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @SimoneVirili If one has a module $M$, and a nonunital commutative algebra that are simultaneously over $B$ and over $A$(e.g.  if $B$ is an $A$ algebra),the homotopy type of the spaces $_AM/I^n$ and $_BM/I^n$ are different.  A good example is with $M=I$ and $n=2$.